# Referencing a table range, based on a column name

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to alter a spreadsheet that currently uses INDIRECT to dynamically determine a column range in a table.  It's really slow.

I have a vba function that will determine the column name, but I now need to reference the column identified by that name.  The end goal is to use it in a SUMIF statement.

Currently uses: `=SUMIFS(My_Table_Name[UNIT_TOTAL],INDIRECT(MyNamedItem),1)`

The value of MyNamedItem is `My_Table_Name[THE_COLUMN]`

I can return `My_Table_Name[THE_COLUMN]` as a string by a function, but then can't pass that into the `SUMIF` as an argument.  How do I return it as a table column range which can be passed as an argument?

The formula could then be: `=SUMIFS(My_table_name[UNIT_TOTAL],My_function_Name(),1)`

Comment: Both INDIRECT and OFFSET volatile functions can almost always be replaced by the non-volatile INDEX. Can you provide a [mcve] that no one has to retype from an image?

Comment: Please use formatting tools to properly edit and format your question/answer.
Codes within sentences are to be formatted as `code` 
Very Important words to be **bold** , lesser important onces *Italic*
Also use lists if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this screenshot:

[image]

The formula in cell K2 is

```
=SUMIFS(Table1[Unit Total],INDEX(Table1,,MATCH(I2,Table1[#Headers],0)),J2)
```

copied down. The table column is calculated dynamically with an Index/Match combo.

Comment: Thank you, that's great.  I will just replace with INDEX.